# why I can't add my answer to readwrite.txt.?

Tags: java, filewriter

I try to add my answer to readwrite.txt, but I don't find my answer every time I run the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<String> category1=new ArrayList<>();
category1.add("die hard");
category1.add("7.5");
category1.add("mission impossible");
category1.add("8");
category1.add("the expendabels");
category1.add("6");
ArrayList<String> category2=new ArrayList<>();
category2.add("the mask");
category2.add("due date");
ArrayList<String>userchoices=new ArrayList<>();
Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("select a movie");
String answer=s.nextLine();

String writepath="files/readwrite.txt";

try {
FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(writepath);
writer.write(answer);
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

if (category1.contains(answer)) {
System.out.println(category1.get(category1.indexOf(answer) + 1) +
(" of 10"));
System.out.println("action");
}
if (answer.equals("action"))
System.out.println(category1);
else if (category2.contains(answer))
System.out.println("comedy");
if (answer.equals("comedy"))
System.out.println(category2);


}
```

}

I try to add my answer to readwrite.txt, but I don't find my answer every time I run the code.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your `FileWriter` when you are done with writing to file. When you call `close()` writer will flush its internal buffer to disk and you will see that text appears in file. Also it is a must to close any resources when you do not need them.

Comment: It works now, but when I rerun the code and type another answer, and read it by FileReader, It only types the last answer, but I want It to type all the answer, why It didn't save all answers?

Comment: @Petersafwat if you want `FileWriter` to append data to existing file instead of overwriting it on each run you need to change your code to `FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(writepath, true);'

Comment: How to remove a specific answer in the text file?

Comment: You cannot delete something from file. You can read everything and then write only stuff you need

Comment: what if I want to add another answer in the next line in the text file, not beside each other?

Comment: Just read documentation for `FileWriter`. There is a lot there